# Proxychains: I can't figure out how to make it work

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, proxychains

[Here](https://pastebin.com/FiXiPJ4R) is my config file. The proxy I use for testing comes from [here](http://free-proxy.cz/en/proxylist/country/GB/https/ping/all).

*I don't want to use Tor.* I just want a normal proxy.

When I run for example `proxychains firefox-esr ipleak.net`:

- if I use exactly the config file from above, I get the error:

```
error: invalid item in proxylist section: https 185.198.189.21 8080
```

- if I change `https` to `http`, I have no error in my terminal, the browser starts, but the page won't load and gives me an error after some time:
  [image]

What am I doing wrong?